# move directories created before a date to another directory?

Tags: linux

In Linux, Is there any command to move all sub directories created before a date to another directory? I have a large directory with more than 3000 sub directories and sub sub directories. Is there any quick command ?

Comment: `find` is your friend: http://linux.die.net/man/1/find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `find` with the `atime` option

```
 find * -type d -atime +number_of_days -exec mv {} /path/to/new_dir \;
```

for more information have a look at the manpage of `find`

Comment: Also look into `mv -t /destination files ...` for making this more efficient, if your `find` has `-exec \+`.